# Custom Post Types posts as submenus in Nav Menu

Tags: menus

I have created a Custom Post Type called "Collections".
I'd like to have in the Nav Menu (no custom menus involved) a menu item 'Collections' that links to the `index` page of Collections Custom Post Type, and hanging from this Menu Item, a list of `n` Submenu Items each linking to a single `post`.

I've done some research and I think there is no literature about the subject. Probably some hooking involved (rewriting the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php) perhaps).

I've managed to have the 'Collections' menu item by declaring `'show_in_nav_menus' => true` in `register_post_type()` but I don't know how to move forward in making the single posts appear as a submenu.

Any help?

Note: using a Thematic Child Theme

Comment: Do you want to generate the single posts sub menu dynamically? What I mean is should it update when a new collection is added or will you be adding them individually yourself?

Comment: it should be automatic. the page would be an index/archive page of the custom post entries, and the submenu would be the titles of each entry, linking to an anchor in the same index/archive page instead than an individual page.

Comment: Hi @NaoiseGolden, this is a really interesting question. Did you ever solve this? If so, please post your answer for others to enjoy. If not, let me know and I'll help you work out the solution.

Comment: Hi @MatthewBoynes I don't recall fixing it (I would've probably answered my own question). Unfortunately I am quite busy now and not working on this any more so I can't help, but would be happy to see an answer for future references.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into it an see if I can come up with something!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on modifying a menu element to add things. In this example, a category item is extended to have a dynamically generated sub menu listing posts, where the menu item has a class of showposts-X where X is the number of posts to show:

```
function menu_show_category_posts( $item_output = '', $item = '', $depth = '', $args = '' ) {
    global $post;

    $item_output = icit_add_class_attrib( $item_output, 'depth-' . ( $depth ? $depth : 1 ) );

    if ( $item->type == 'taxonomy' && $item->object == 'category' && is_array( $item->classes ) ) {
        $query = false;
        $showposts = 10;
        $preview = 0;
        $new_html = array( );
        $i = 0;

        foreach( $item->classes as $class ) {
            if ( preg_match( '/^showposts-?(\d*)/', $class, $matches ) ) {
                $query = true;
                $showposts = ! empty( $matches[ 1 ] ) && intval( $matches[ 1 ] ) ? intval( $matches[ 1 ] ) : 10;
            }
        }

        if ( $query ) {
            $the_posts = get_posts( array(
                             'category' => $item->object_id,
                             'numberposts' => $showposts
                            ) );

            if ( ! empty( $the_posts ) ) {
                $new_html[] = '<ul class="sub-menu">';

                foreach( ( array ) $the_posts as $post ) {
                    setup_postdata( $post );
                    $new_html[] = '<li class="">';
                    $new_html[] = the_title( '<a href="' . get_permalink( ) . '" class="depth-' . ( $depth ? $depth + 1 : 2 ) . '">', '</a>', false );
                    $new_html[] = '</li>';
                }

                $new_html[] = '</ul>';
                $item_output .= implode( "\n", $new_html );
            }
        }
    }

    return $item_output;
}

add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'menu_show_media_post', 10, 4 );
```